# A better way to prove this inequality

Tags: inequality, notation, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, tangent-line-method

**Exercise 1.1.6. (b)** For positive real numbers $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ prove that

$$(a_1+a_2+ \ldots +a_n)\Big(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{a_n}\Big) \geq n^2.$$

---

From $AM \geq GM$:

$$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n \geq n\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2 \ldots a_n}$$
$$a_2a_3 \ldots a_n + a_1a_3 \ldots a_n + \ldots + a_1a_2 \ldots a_{n-1} \geq n\sqrt[n]{(a_1a_2 \ldots a_n)^{n-1}}$$

Multiply,
$$(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)(a_2a_3 \ldots a_n + a_1a_3 \ldots a_n + \ldots + a_1a_2 \ldots a_{n-1}) \geq n^2 \cdot a_1a_2 \ldots a_n$$

$$(a_1+a_2+ \ldots +a_n)\Big(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{a_n}\Big) \geq n^2.$$

---

I'm not satisfied with this. I'm looking for a better way to prove it...or at least a better way to *write it (notation)*.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2134362/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/440761/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1871864/42969

Answer (score 14):

That's just the [AM-HM inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) written differently:

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+ \ldots +a_n}{n} \ge \frac{n}{\cfrac{1}{a_1}+\cfrac{1}{a_2}+ \ldots +\cfrac{1}{a_n}}$$

Answer (score 6):

Since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $$a_1+a_2+...+a_n=n$$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}\geq n,$$
which is true because $$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}-n=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{a_i}-1\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{a_i}-1+a_i-1\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(a_i-1)^2}{a_i}\geq0.$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
n^{2}&=\left(\sqrt{a_{1}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_{1}}}+\cdots+\sqrt{a_{n}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n}}}\right)^{2}\\
&\leq\left(a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}\right)
\end{align*}
by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 3):

Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)\ge\left[\sqrt{a_1}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_1}}+\sqrt{a_2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{a_n}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_n}}\right]^2$$

A.M.-G.M.

$$(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)\ge\left(n\cdot\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}\right)\left(n\cdot\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$(a_1+a_2+ \ldots +a_n)\Big(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{a_n}\Big) = ((\sqrt{a_1})^2+(\sqrt{a_2})^2+ \ldots +(\sqrt{a_n})^2)\Big(\frac{1}{(\sqrt{a_1})^2}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt{a_2})^2}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{(\sqrt{a_n})^2}\Big) \geq (1 + 1 + \ldots + 1)^2 = n^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Nothing except $a+\frac 1a\geqslant 2\sqrt{a\cdot\frac 1a}=2$ for $a,b>0:$

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k\cdot \sum\limits_{m=1}^n \frac1{a_m}=\sum\limits_{k=m=1}^n 1+\sum\limits_{1\leqslant k<m\leqslant n} \left(\frac{a_m}{a_k}+\frac{a_k}{a_m}\right)\geqslant n + \sum\limits_{1\leqslant k<m\leqslant n} 2=n+\binom {n}{2}\cdot 2=n^2$